# RSA Encryption Using Generated Key Pair

Tags: python

I have been stuck on this problem since morning. I have generated key pair for RSA encryption using ssh-keygen.

Encryption works fine:

```
with open("keys.pub", "rb") as f:
    pubkey = f.read()

with open("keys", "rb") as f:
    prvkey = f.read()

from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5 as Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5

msg = "test"
print("raw msg->", msg)
keyPub = RSA.importKey(pubkey) # import the public key
cipher = Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5.new(keyPub)
cipher_text = cipher.encrypt(msg.encode()) # now we have the cipher
print("cipher text->", cipher_text)
```

However, I get error in decryption:

```
keyPriv = RSA.importKey(prvkey) # import the private key
cipher = Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5.new(keyPriv)
decrypt_text = cipher.decrypt(cipher_text, None).decode()
print("decrypted msg->", decrypt_text)
assert msg == decrypt_text # check that
print("test passed")
```

> ValueError: RSA key format is not supported

I am using PyCrypto 2.6.1. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am not able to attach the keys due to to some server error.

Answer (score 0):

After you issue RSA.importKey, does the variable keyPriv contain the key correctly?

It seems that the RSA key pairs generated by you is not compatible with pycrypto 2.6.1. Installing pycryptodome 3, which is a fork of pycrypto and is under active development, should resolve the issue.